# Immutable.js with React Pure Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I'm having some trouble using React `PureComponent`s with Immutable.js. Consider the following demo:

https://codepen.io/SandoCalrissian/pen/QaEmeX

In it 2 components are rendered.  The first (`NoramlPure`) is a normal `PureComponent` while the second (`ImmutablePure`) is a normal `Component` with a custom `shouldComponentUpdate` that checks props for an `equals` method.  Both take a single Immutable `Map` as a prop which is re-formed on every render cycle.  Both also print a message to the console every time they re-render.

I then trigger two render cycles.

I'm expecting both to only render once.  *However*, the console shows the following:

```
rendering
    rendering normal pure component
    rendering immutable pure component
rendering
    rendering normal pure component
```

My custom component works as expected, but the built in `PureComponent` renders both times (despite getting the same data).

Seeing as React links to Immutable.js [in the documentation for `PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) (and since they're both made by Facebook) I'd sort of expect the two to work together naturally, but as far as I can tell `PureComponent`s don't ever call any Immutable.js equality checkers.

**Is there any way to make `PureComponent`s work with Immutable.js objects?
  Or am I stuck using my `PureImmutable` component as a base-class across my entire project?**

Comment: Pure component works with Immutable data, please add relevant code so that people can identify the problem

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri It's in the CodePen I've linked above

Comment: @SandyGifford You could create a library from that ImmutablePure component. I think it is more useful than the react-immutable-pure-component library which uses a new interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi Sandy the problem is that in each render you are recreating the map prop and React.PureComponent is basically checking props.map === nextProps.map. They are different so it re-render.

Check this one:

```
class NormalPure extends React.PureComponent<any, any> {
  public render() {
    console.log("\trendering normal pure component");
    return <div />;
  }
}

class ImmutablePure extends React.Component<any, any> {
  public shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return !Object.keys(this.props).every((key) => {
      const val = this.props[key];
      const nextVal = nextProps[key];

      if (typeof val.equals === "function")  {
        return val.equals(nextVal);
      } else {
        return val === nextVal;
      }
    });
  }

  public render() {
    console.log("\trendering immutable pure component");
    return <div />;
  }
}

const wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

const obj = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3,
};

const immutableMap = Immutable.fromJS(obj);

function render() {
  console.log("rendering");

  ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
      <NormalPure map={immutableMap} />
      <ImmutablePure map={Immutable.fromJS(obj)} />
    </div>,
    wrapper
  );
}

render();
render();
```

**Is there any way to make PureComponents work with Immutable.js objects?** No. PureComponent use a strict equality comparison (===). It dosen't know about Immutablejs

**Or am I stuck using my PureImmutable component as a base-class across my entire project?** Yes, if you want to check Immutablejs objects with the equals method.

Comment: Then it's not really working with Immutable, I don't think.  The same is true for comparing simple object literals... `(function(o) { console.log(o === o); })({ "a": 1 })` prints `true`.

Comment: Edits answer my question.  Thanks!

Comment: That's a little frustrating seeing as they both come from Facebook and reference each other in the documentation, but understandable, I guess...

Comment: The problem is that Immutable.js is just a library, they could implement it but not everybody use that library. On the other hand strict equality comparison is a language feature.

Comment: These libraries although both coming from facebook have separated concerns. You could use both of them individually. It's not a good idea to try make every framework fully compatible with every other framework you might want to use it with. Usually if two frameworks work well together you'll find a bridging framework providing the glue code, e.g. `react-redux`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can use this `ImmutablePureComponent` implementation instead of the standard `PureComponent`:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-immutable-pure-component